# Implementing CSS style for page breaks "breaks" the tables of contents in R Markdown

Tags: html, css, r, markdown, wkhtmltopdf

Owing to issues with getting my document to look pleasing in knitr's export to pdf, I'm converting the html file for my Markdown project to pdf through the [wkhtmltopdf](https://wkhtmltopdf.org/) cmd line utility tool.

A very basic Markdown doc replicates my issue:

```
---
title: "Untitled"
output: 
  html_document:
    df_print: paged
    toc: true
    number_sections: true
---

## ALPHA Header

### Alpha sub-1

### Alpha sub-2

## BETA Header

### Beta sub-1

### Beta sub-2
```

This generates a html file with the table of contents - but no page breaks when I go to convert this file through wkhtmltopdf.

I sourced answers from [this](https://github.com/wkhtmltopdf/wkhtmltopdf/issues/2982) Github query, trying to implement the custom CSS style type recommended. Note, I don't really know much html/CSS.

I modified the markdown code after the YAML (which remains unchanged) by:

```
<style type="text/css" media="screen,print">
       /* Page Breaks */

/***Always insert a page break before the element***/
       .pb_before {
           page-break-before: always !important;
       }
</style>

<div class="page1 pb_before">
## ALPHA Header
</div>
<div class="page2 pb_before">
### Alpha sub-1
</div>
<div class="page3 pb_before">
### Alpha sub-2
</div>
<div class="page4 pb_before">
## BETA Header
</div>
<div class="page5 pb_before">
### Beta sub-1
</div>
<div class="page6 pb_before">
### Beta sub-2
</div>
```

Knitting this version, the numbering system for the headers and the table of contents have disappeared, however now when I go to convert the html file to pdf by wkhtmltopdf, I now get a seperate page for each header.

So my question is - how do I synthesise the two together, whereby I have a table of contents and numbered headers after exporting to html, as well as having html/CSS code prepped to allow me to have page breaks after each header when I've converted through wkhtmltopdf.

Comment: "Note that Markdown formatting syntax is not processed within block-level HTML tags." ([see the rules](https://daringfireball.net/projects/markdown/syntax#html)). However, depending on which tool you are using to convert your Markdown to HTML, there may be a workaround for this.

Comment: @Waylan I'm using the standard R markdown facilities in RStudio

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I found a hacky solution for this:

Insert:

```
<div class="page1 pb_after">
&nbsp;
</div>
```

Before every header I want a seperate page for.